One consumer from different topics with the same key
I have a use case where I have 2 different topics, coming from 2 different applications/producers, where the events in them are related by the key (e.g. a userID).
For the sake of sequential processing and avoiding race conditions, I want to process all data related to a specific key (e.g. a specific user) in the same consumer.
What are the suggested solutions for this?
According to https://www.reddit.com/r/apachekafka/comments/16lzlih/in_apache_kafka_if_you_have_2_partitions_and_2/ I can't assume the consumer will be assigned the correlated partitions even when the number of partitions is the same across the topic.
Should I just create a 3rd topic to aggregate them? I'm assuming there is some built in Kafka connect that does this?
I'm using Kafka with Spring if it matters.

Right. There is no guarantee which record would arrive first and from what consumer instance. I'm not sure how the third topic could help here, but this task really could be achieved with Kafka Streams: https://developer.confluent.io/courses/kafka-streams/hands-on-aggregations/
Or if you are interested more in Spring solution then take a look into an aggregator implementation in Spring Integration: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/aggregator.html

Thanks. Ordering between the topics is not important.

Then you may really think about sending those records with the same key to a third topic where they would land in the the same partition according to that key.
